# Expression must be a list type: Map<Id

Tags: apex, trigger

I have old code all the logic is in the Trigger and I'm moving away from trigger to handle all the logic in class and I'm stuck here and not sure what is the best approach to handle it and I could have done something like this `Trigger.oldMap.keyset()`

This is my old code resides in Trigger:

```
  if(trigger.isdelete)
    {
       List<Offer__c> ofr = [select id, Attachment__c from Offer_c where id =: Trigger.Old[0].ParentId];
      /* ... more code */
    }
```

New Code: Update to TriggerHandler in a separate class:

```
public static void attAfterDeleteOperation(List<Offer__c> newList, Map<Id,Offer__c> oldMap)
{
   List<Offer__c> ofr = [select id, Attachment__c from Offer_c where id =: oldMap[0].ParentId]; //how do you handle here <<<<
}
```

Error:

```
Error   Error: Compile Error: Expression must be a list type: Map<Id,Offer__c>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're only processing the first item in the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oldMap` variable is a Map, so you'll need to get the values:

`List <Offer__c> offers = oldMap.values();`

and then you can use `offers[0].ParentId` in your query binding